# Storing content in Sqlite database through IntentService blocks the UI thread

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, intentservice

I have lots of records which I pull from the webservice and I need to cache them locally. While doing this (over 1000 records) the UI thread is blocked and I get ANR warning. I thought that using IntentService for that will not block the UI. What as I doiung wrong?

Few code snippets:

```
public class ContentIntentService extends IntentService {

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    code = workIntent.getStringExtra("CODE");
    getContent(code);
}

private void getContent(final String code) {
    if (apiService == null) {
        Retrofit client = ApiClient.getClient();
        if (client != null)
            apiService = client.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
    if (apiService == null) {
        MobileValetHelper.onConnectionFailed(mAppContext);
        return;
    }
    Call<SectionsResponse> call = apiService.getOutletContent(outletCode, outletCode, MobileValetHelper.getContentSessionToken(mAppContext));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SectionsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<SectionsResponse> call, @NonNull Response<SectionsResponse> response) {
            if (response != null
                    && response.body() != null
                    && response.body().status != null
                    && response.body().status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")
                    && response.body().sessionToken != null
                    && response.body().data != null
                    ) {
                        DataCacheHelper dataCacheHelper = new DataCacheHelper(ContentIntentService.this);
                        dataCacheHelper.insertItems(ContentIntentService.this, items);
                    }
            } else if (response != null
                    && response.errorBody() != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getContent response.errorBody(): " + response.errorBody().string());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<SectionsResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getContent onFailure: " + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

public class DataCacheHelper {
        private ContentIntentService mIntentService;

```
    public DataCacheHelper(ContentIntentService service) {
        mIntentService = service;
    }

    public void insertItems(final ArrayList<CategoryItem> items) {

        if (mIntentService != null && items != null) {
            try {
                ContentValues[] valueList = new ContentValues[items.size()];
                int i = 0;
                ContentValues values;
                for (final CategoryItem item : items) {
                    values = ItemsTable.getContentValues(item);
                    valueList[i++] = values;
                }
                context.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(provider.CONTENT_URI, valueList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how are you starting the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never do something asynchronous from an `IntentService`. Once `onHandleIntent()` returns, the `IntentService` will be destroyed. In your case, the network I/O may still be going on, let alone the disk I/O.

Second, `onResponse()` is called on the main application thread, which is the source of your difficulty.

So, use `execute()` instead of `enqueue()` and do all of the work directly in the `IntentService` on the thread used for `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: Thanks :) Helped me.